# Slicing (x,y) coordinates and data out of multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

I have Googled and searched on here for an answer to my problem and have not come across an answer. I have found ample info on *slicing* and using `np.where`, of which I am using but I have a problem slicing some arrays, it doesn't appear to be doing what I want.

What i need: Take the same slice through a vertical set of `(x, y)` and data arrays.

I have `3` arrays that are 2D `(n, m)` for now, where `n` and `m` will change depending on what data set I'm looking at but are all the same for the same dataset. The arrays are `X_new`, `Y_new` and `ZED_H`, that is `x` and `y` coordinates and the data `ZED_H`.

`X_new` and `Y_new` coordinates are different for each `ZED_H`, but not massively different. Imagine that my arrays are vertically stacked where the `0th` is at the bottom up to the `Nth` at the top. `X_new` and `Y_new` are an *irregular* grid. Once they become sliced (isolated) they are then interpolated to a *regular* grid.

What I do: I find the *maximum value* in the `0th` data, maximum *reflectivity* in my case, this gives me an `i`, `j` from which I can find the `(x, y)`. I then make arbitrary `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` coordinates which define a "box" around the *maximum*. This bit works. I then need to pass in each set of `X_new`, `Y_new` and `ZED_H` and out of these arrays slice the data that corresponds to be within `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax`. These *max's* and *min's* are all withing each `(x, y)` arrays.

Essentially take the same vertical box slice given by the bottom data through the vertical stack of data.

The code:

```
# find the x indices
idx = np.where((X_new >= xmin) & (X_new <= xmax))
# find the y indices
idy = np.where((Y_new >= ymin) & (Y_new <= ymax))

# slice the x and y coordinates out of the whole arrays
x_st_Z = X_new[idx[0][0]:idx[0][-1],idx[1][0]:idx[1][-1]]
y_st_Z = Y_new[idy[0][0]:idy[0][-1],idy[1][0]:idy[1][-1]]
# slice my isolated data out of the whole array
#storm_Z = ZED_H[???] # not sure what to slice with here
```

I have tried many forms of using `np.where` to try and get it to work but it doesn't. So `idx` and `idy` should return the `i`, `j` indices for where any `(x, y)` passed in meets the condition, within the `min` and `max` values. I then use these to *slice* `X_new` and `Y_new` to give the "isolated" coordinates and isolated data. I'm not sure how to *slice* the data correctly. The *sliced* X_new and Y_new also works *incorrectly*, returning the *whole* `X_new` and `Y_new` as the conditions in `idx` and `idy` are not been met, which I can't understand why. I think it should return the indices of where `X_new > xmin` and `X_new < xmax` and so on.

I don't understand whats going wrong. I'm clearly missing something and some logic in my understanding.

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated as I've spent a long time trying to understand this and its just not clicking.

Thanks
Liam

Comment: Are the x and y coordinates a regular grid (identical rows or columns) or an irregular scattered layout.  I'd suggest adding a sample set of arrays.  Any answer will have to provide such a set to demonstrate the action.  You can make that task easier.

Comment: What do you get when you type `X_new.shape`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment hpaulj, i've added the grid info to the question. Ebe Isaac, i get (259L, 666L) so all the X_new and Y_new for this data set are the same shape. Thanks

Comment: Please post a minimal example of ```X_new``` and ```Y_new``` - an example that has enough info for testing.

Comment: ...also include a simple `ZED_H` if possible.

Comment: I can, I've not had to provide data on here before. Could you suggest the easiest way to include it. A print out is very long. Thank you.

Comment: Just show the output of `print(X_new.shape, Y_new.shape, ZED_H.shape)`

Comment: ((259L, 666L), (259L, 666L), (259L, 666L)) This is the shapes for one level. All other levels are the same shape. So i have temporarily stored each level in a list. You will only need these shapes as these are what are passed into the indexing code.

Comment: It's a little odd how X and Y be 2D matrices themselves. What does each row and each column mean in all three matrices?

Comment: So X and Y are calculated from the range and azimuth from some radar data. The code that does this was provided to me. The row should relate to azimuth and the column to range. In the ZED_H this is the corresponding radar reflectivity at these X and Y.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: `X_new` is a matrix with each row containing an array of x coordinates, and similarly `Y_new` contains y coordinates. So, for a given row `r` of azimuth and some range value `c`, `(X_new[r,c], Y_new[r,c])` is the (x,y) coordinate for which `ZED_H[r,c]` is the data value.

Comment: Yes X_new are the X coordinates and Y_new for the Y coordinates. Yes `(X_new[r,c], Y_new[r,c])` correspond to `ZED_H[r,c]`

Comment: Then it's solved. I'll be posting my answer shortly, Liam.

Comment: Ok thats great, yeah so as long as each `r,c` in X and Y correspond to the data in `ZED_H` thats fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution for your problem:

```
X1 = X_new.ravel()
Y1 = Y_new.ravel()
Z1 = ZED_H.ravel()

idx = np.all([X1 >= xmin, X1 <= xmax],axis=0)
idy = np.all([Y1 >= ymin, Y1 <= ymax],axis=0)

storm_Z = Z1[idx & idy]
```

`storm_Z` is a 1D array that contains all values of `ZED_H` for which it's corresponding `X_new` and `Y_new` are within the respective min-max boundaries.
`X1[idx]` and `Y1[idy]` give the sliced values of `X_new` and `Y_new` respectively.

If you want to preserve at which row (azimuth), the storm values were extracted, then you could do the following

```
nRows = X_new.shape[0]

storm_Z = []

for i in range(nRows):
    X1 = X_new[i]
    Y1 = Y_new[i]
    Z1 = ZED_H[i]

    idx = np.all([X1 >= xmin, X1 <= xmax],axis=0)
    idy = np.all([Y1 >= ymin, Y1 <= ymax],axis=0)

    storm_Z.append(Z1[idx & idy])
```

Note that storm_Z is a *ragged array* meaning that it may not be regular; it is a list of lists with all rows needing not to be the same length. So if you really want a matrix, you would have to pad the non-existent cells with some other values like `0` or `None`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Ebe Isaac. I've been looking at it and have a question. Should `storm_Z = Z1[idx1 & idx2]` be `storm_Z = Z1[idx & idy]`. Also the shapes im getting returned are (18477L,) (39848L,) (3520L,), for `X1[idx]`, `Y1[idy]` and `storm_Z`. So i need to pad the shorter ones out and then i would be able to reshape them?.